# Error while getting an image from a soap web service into an android application

Tags: android, web-services, soap, imageview

I am trying to get a image from the server through a SOAP web service into an android application.I am getting some error on that.
I am trying to receive the image in byte array from the web service.
My codes are-

The web service code is-

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "GetDiseasePic")
public byte[] picFromServer(@WebParam(name = "file_name") String filename) {
    String filePath = "C:/Users/Ashraful/Desktop/layout/icons/" + filename;
    System.out.println("Sending file: " + filePath);

    try {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        byte[] fileBytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        inputStream.read(fileBytes);
        inputStream.close();

        return fileBytes;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
        throw new WebServiceException(ex);
    }

}
```

The activity of my android application is-

```
private void imageSelect() {

final String NAMESPACE_D_PIC = "http://DiseaseInformationWS/"; // target namespace of the Web service available

final String METHOD_NAME_D_PIC = "GetDiseasePic";// Name of the method in the Webservice file

final String SOAP_ACTION_D_PIC = "http://DiseaseInformationWS/GetDiseasePic"; // SoapAction that consists of the NAMESPACE+ METHOD_NAME1

final String URL_D_PIC = "http://"+IpchangeInteface.IPADDRESS+":8080/AshrafThesisWebService/DiseaseWebSer vice?wsdl";

    new AsyncTask<String,Void, Bitmap>(){
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }


        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

            SoapObject request_d_pic = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE_D_PIC,METHOD_NAME_D_PIC);
            request_d_pic.addProperty("file_name",imagefilename);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelop_d_pic = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER10);
            envelop_d_pic.setOutputSoapObject(request_d_pic);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport_d_pic = new HttpTransportSE(URL_D_PIC);

            try {
                androidHttpTransport_d_pic.call(SOAP_ACTION_D_PIC,envelop_d_pic);

                SoapObject result_d_pic = (SoapObject) envelop_d_pic.bodyIn;
                SoapObject result_d_picSP = (SoapObject) envelop_d_pic.bodyIn;
                String getresult = result_d_pic.toString();
                Log.d("IMAGEFILE",getresult);
                if (getresult!=""){
                 filebyte = Base64.decode(getresult,Base64.DEFAULT);
                    bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(filebyte,0,filebyte.length);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmapImage;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if(bitmapImage!=null) {
                diseasePic.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);
            }
        }

    }.execute();
}
```

The error i am getting is-

```
05-25 20:33:47.282 3184-3249/com.thesiswork.ashraf.ashrafresearchwork E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
                                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64
                                                                                        at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:161)
                                                                                        at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:136)
                                                                                        at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:118)
                                                                                        at com.thesiswork.ashraf.ashrafresearchwork.Disease_InformationScreen$5.doInBackground(Disease_InformationScreen.java:410)
                                                                                        at com.thesiswork.ashraf.ashrafresearchwork.Disease_InformationScreen$5.doInBackground(Disease_InformationScreen.java:384)
                                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
                                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```

Please suggest me what to do now??

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
filebyte = Base64.decode(getresult, Base64.NO_PADDING);
```

Comment: Its giving me the same error even after applying your suggestion @Tabassum

Comment: Please someone help me in this issue.

Comment: if you are storing your image base64 string in database so check that field type is Text or other if is Text then image is save fine else not that why getting error